# What does $LS$ coupling and $jj$ coupling signify?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals

When we consider $1s2p$ electrons in $LS$ coupling we get one singlet and one triplet but in $jj$ coupling, we get $2$ doublets.
I know the mathematical (quantum number) work behind it.
But what I don't understand is that why is that so?!  why is there a difference in the multiplicity of the splitting when considered $LS$ coupling and $jj$ coupling even though vectorailly and mathematically they represent the same scenarios ?!

What makes the thing different in both the coupling ?!
And which one is right ?! And why?!
Does it imply that the electrons in an atom prefer to interact in some special ($LS$ for lighter and $jj$ for heavier atoms) steps?!

And, most important, how can one prove mathematically that there exists such a preferred steps ?!

Comment: Not to mention that in certain complex cases one even uses LSjj or jjLS schemes.